# Valerius and Valentinus have the same root?

Tags: etymology

[Valerius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeria_(gens)#Origin) is derived from "Volesus" or "Volusus", which in turn is derived from "*valere*", to be strong.

[Valentinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentinus) is derived from "*valens*" meaning "healthy, strong"

So "valere" comes from "valens"?

Answer (score 3):

*Valens* is the present active participle of *valēre*: "being strong".

Comment: And what is the connection betwen "valeō" and "valere"?

Comment: @Ark25 They are the same thing. They are different forms of the same verb, and you can use either one to refer to it. More precisely, *valeo* is "I am strong" and *valere* is "to be strong".